# Not able to commit anything

Tags: git

I just changed my machine so I cloned my repository to the new machine but I am not able to work on that machine whenever I try to commit the following message shows up.

```
> git add . && git commit -m " few changes "
```

getting this message :

```
> On branch master
  Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

  nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Run `git status` and check whether or not anything in fact is present in the stage.  If the stage be _empty_, then your `git add .` didn't do anything, or at least it didn't do what you thought it was doing.

Comment: Are you sure you're changing files in the git folder, and not in another folder? and are those files tracked by git?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen tried git status stil this message showed up  git status 
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Then you made no changes.

Comment: @AndyRay yes made few changes git is not detecting it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I indeed made some changes, moreover, I added new files to the dir but still same issue

Comment: Read the above comments.  It is likely that the changes you made are not inside the folder being tracked by Git.

Comment: Maybe the changes you made are ignored (`.gitignore`)?

Comment: @yoda try `git add --all`. See if this works for you.

Comment: @PankajSinghal his `git status` got nothing ^^

Comment: it seems like git is not tracking the changes made inside the files is there any way to reset that I am using the git that comes preinstalled in macOS

Comment: It's more likely that 1) you are not in the correct folder that contains the git repo, or 2) your changes are git ignored. I suggest checking the output of `git status --long --ignored`, make sure that your changes are not listed under "Ignored files:". Then, I suggest repeating the `git clone <project>` step, `cd`-ing to the `<project>` folder, and repeating the same changes.